# parser and lexer generator php

Tags: php

I am doing a academic work that I need to use parser and lexer generator for php.
I searched on the internet and I found [this](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_ParserGenerator/docs/latest/)

The problem is create the grammar and plex file. 
For example:

```
<?php
class blah {
/*!lex2php
%input $this->data
%counter $this->N
%token $this->token
%value $this->value
%line $this->line
variable = @/?:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?@
*/
/*!lex2php
variable {$a = 1;}
*/
}
?>
```

Someone can explain me that code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first comment block is used for declarations. All the % declaration are mostly for internal use, and not very relevant at this stage.
The `variable = @/?:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?@` is interesting though. It defines a [nonterminal symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols#Nonterminal_symbols) `variable`, defined by the regex `@/?:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?@`.

If you generate your lexer using this plex file and feed it something like this:

```
234lksdf lskdjf324 kl234jd
```

The tokenstream would be as follows:

```
token: variable
value: 234lksdf 

token: variable
value: lskdjf324 

token: variable
value: kl234jd
```